# SwiftUI: Как локализировать DatePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui

У меня есть DatePicker в эмуляторе установлен русский язык, но почему-то в DatePicker всё на английском языке (дни недели, месяцы).
Как можно управлять локализацией?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сменить язык на русский в Симуляторе/Телефоне в настройках.
DatePicker должен локализовываться под капотом

Answer (score 0):

Для смены языка в симуляторе:

1. `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...`
2. На вкладке `Options` в поле `App Language` выберите нужный язык
3. Симулятор должен его подхватить.

Для смены языка в приложении "на лету":

1. Объявить переменную:

   ```
   @State var selectedLanguage: String = ""
   ```
2. Реализовать выбор языка к примеру так:

   ```
   List{
       Button{selectedLanguage = "en"} label:{
           Label("english")
       }
       Button{selectedLanguage = "ru"} label:{
           Label("русский")
       }
   }
   ```
3. Примените окружение:

   ```
   VStack {
   ...
   } 
   .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: selectedLanguage))
   ```